# ImageMapType "get tile" timeout or retry properties?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Wondering if the Google Maps v3 API ImageMapType object has a default timeout for the "get tile" (getTileUrl) functionality when loading tiles from an external source?

We've noticed some tiles get aborted so was wondering if a timeout or retry parameter exists to augment that behavior?